# how to make for loop over Numpy array to get each row in a separate record

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I have these two files:
the first one looks like that:

```
| #Gene    | Sample1    | Sample2  |
| -------- | ---------- | ---------|
| Gene1    | 1          | 2        |
| Gene2    | 4          | 6        |
| Gene3    | 3          | 6        |
| Gene4    | 2          | 1        |
| Gene5    | 4          | 2        |
```

the second one looks like that:

```
| #Gene    | Sample1    | Sample2  |
| -------- | ---------- | ---------|
| Gene1    | 3          | 5        |
| Gene2    | 2          | 3        |
| Gene3    | 3          | 7        |
| Gene4    | 2          | 3        |
| Gene5    | 2          | 6        |



import numpy as np
GE1 = np.loadtxt(file1_path, skiprows=1, delimiter='\t', usecols=range(1,2))
GE2 = np.loadtxt(file2_path, skiprows=1, delimiter='\t', usecols=range(1,5))
```

how to use for loop over GE1 and GE2 to get every row values in a separate record??

Comment: What do you mean *get every row values in a separate record* ? Can you share your expected output ?

Comment: I want to get for example this output:
gene1_samples1 = [ values of first row] #get the expression values of gene 1 across the samples of GE1.
gene2_samples1 = [values of first row] ##get the expression values of gene 1 across the samples of GE2.
and so on until gene 5

Comment: Are those the actual files, or a fancy table display?  `loadtxt` is best for simple CSV - comma separated values, though it can have other delimiters like `tab`.  But tab doesn't show up properly in a copy-n-paste.  If the `loadtxt` work, show the actual `GE1` and `GE2`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your goal is to read the data into an array, this looks like a use case for [`np.fromregex`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html).

```py
>>> pattern = r"""\|\s*Gene\d\s+\|\s*(\d+)\s*\|\s*(\d+)"""
>>> array = np.fromregex(some_file, pattern, int)
array([[3, 5],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 7]])
```